# How ro seperate between 2 related sql queries using PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, left-join

I have a PHP code with a MySQL database and javascript that select data from the database and display it on Google map using 3 dependent dropdown list

The problem is that I have 2 SQL queries where one depends on the result of the other.

I need to get just one result from the first SQL query in order to compared in the second SQL query.

SQL query #1:

```
<!--  the below part  of code work as it should   --!>
<!--create  dropdown list site names-->

<form method ="post" action ="" name="submit_form">
        <table border="0" width="30%">
            <tr>
               <td>Site Name</td>
               <td>Owner Name</td>
               <td>Company Name</td>
               <td>Subcontractor Name</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
               <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">
                      <option value="">Select Site</option>
                 <?php


                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT 
                        i.siteNAME, 
                        i.ownerID, 
                        i.companyID,
                        o.ownerNAME,
                        x.companyNAME
                       from site_info i
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN owner_info o
                       on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
                       LEFT  
                       JOIN company_info x
                       on i.companyID = x.companyID
                       ");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $row)
                      {
                      echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID.", ".$row ->companyID.",".$row ->ownerNAME.",".$row ->companyNAME.",".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";

                       //echo "<option value = ' ".$row ->ownerNAME.",".$row ->companyNAME.",".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";


                     var_dump($query_site_name);
                      } 

                 ?>

                </select></td>
```

where in the below SQL query, the variable `$site_name` will take the result from the first SQL query.

SQL query #2:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
     , i.siteNAME
     , i.equipmentTYPE
     , c.latitude
     , c.longitude
     , c.height 
     , o.ownerNAME
     , o.ownerCONTACT
     , x.companyNAME
     , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
     , y.subcontractorNAME
     , y.subcontractorCONTACT
  from site_info i
  LEFT  
  JOIN owner_info o
    on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
  LEFT  
  JOIN company_info x
    on i.companyID = x.companyID
  LEFT 
  JOIN subcontractor_info y
    on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c
    on i.siteID=c.siteID 
    where 
    i.siteNAME = %s
    AND 
    o.ownerNAME = %s
    AND 
    x.companyNAME = %s
   ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);

 $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
echo $sql;
```

[image]

as it shows in the image the first variable has many values where what I want is just the  word **Bsalim**  in order to display the marker on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if answers your question, but why once you receive the result from the first query you don't apply a regex to catch just the name that you want (There should be a pattern on the database result for the site_name) an then when you perform the second query you just enter the result of the regex?

If necessary on the second query you can search partial names like %Bsalim%.

Hope it helped.

Comment: my question is how can i select just the desired value from the first query without selecting the hall including values ?

Comment: The best solution passes from getting the info from the column (assuming that the info on that column follows a pattern, for you to be able to get all the expected result and treat it outside) because from my POV all the info on the column will be retrieved. You can't get just partial strings of the column in this case. After getting the column with a regex you can extract just the "Bsalim" and use it on the next query.